# Next up vs up next

Tags: difference, phrases

When you watch TV programs such as *British Got Talent*, the TV hosts sometimes say:

> ''**Next up** is the talented singer from...'' (performers number or sequencing method kind of thing)

Whereas, when you play Youtube, then there a window on the uppermost right corner link indicating **''up next''**.

What is the difference between **up next** and **next up**?

I've been seeing this for a long time, and I'm not sure why they have to change this every now then, or maybe there's a real difference between both. I googled it but none of the results answered my question.

Comment: How about finding and posting some examples? We need examples of usage.

Comment: I can't think of any real difference, but it might depend on context.

Comment: Could you make up some examples anyway? My guess would be that the *up* in "next up" leads into a prepositional phrase, while "up next" would stand by itself.

Comment: @Lambie, I already did it here on the site, you can see my involvement in another topic there while they asked me to do another question page.

Comment: John Arvin: You've had three active members ask you for more context, yet you've stubbornly refused to add any. You said, "I've been seeing this for a long time" – well, then, you should be able to furnish an example or two. You said, "I googled it but none of them answered my question" – well, you could at least tell us what you googled so we won't make the same mistake, and so we can have a better idea of what confuses you. The more you put into a question, the more you (and everyone else) will get out of a question.

Comment: Peace, I just got online but I already edited it. Is that clear now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Up next... next up. Next in... in next. Last in... in last. Reversible idioms. We vary our speech so as not to sound like robots. There is very rarely only one way to say something.

Answer (score 3):

There really is no difference between the two phrases.  The only time they might be used in the same setting is to avoid sounding repetitious.  So if you were introducing 50 performers in a row it would sound less monotonous to mix up your phrasing a little.

Comment: citrus128 is clearly correct and your Question was clearly worth the research you posted.

Wha`t did I miss, there, please?

Comment: It's not "British Got Talent", it's "Britain's Got Talent".